# Laravel 5.3 - Blade not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

When I try to load my project on web browser. It shows header and footer, but the middle section containing form is missing, and I don't understand what am I doing wrong?

views/welcome.blade:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
@include('partials._head')
</head>
<body>
         @include('partials._nav')


         <div class="container">

         @include('partials._messages')
         @yield('content')
         @include('partials._footer')

         </div>


         @include('partials._javascript')

 </body>
 </html>
```

views/user_auth/user_register.blade:

```
@extends('welcome')

@section('title')
Welcome!!
@endsection

@section('content')

{!! Form::open(['route' => 'signup']) !!}

{{ Form::label('user_name','Name:') }}
{{ Form::text('user_name',null,['class' => 'form-control']) }}

{{ Form::label('email','E-mail:') }}
{{ Form::text('email',null,['class' => 'form-control']) }}

{{ Form::label('mobile_num','Mobile No.:') }}
{{ Form::text('mobile_num',null,['class' => 'form-control']) }}

{{ Form::label('address','Address:') }}
{{ Form::text('address',null,['class' => 'form-control']) }}

{{ Form::label('state','State:') }}
{{ Form::text('state',null,['class' => 'form-control']) }}

{{ Form::label('city','City:') }}
{{ Form::text('city',null,['class' => 'form-control']) }}

{{ Form::label('district','District:') }}
{{ Form::text('district',null,['class' => 'form-control']) }}


{{ Form::submit('Register',array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-  block form-spacing-top')) }}

{!! Form::close() !!}
@endsection
```

RegisterController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{

public function getRegistrationPage()
   {  

         return view('user_auth.user_register');
   }
public function postSignUp(Request $request)
 {
    $this -> validate($request,[  
      'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
      'name'  => 'required|max:20',
      'mobile_num' => 'required|digits:10',
      'address' => 'required',
      'city' => 'required',
      'district' => 'required',
      'state' => 'required',
      'password' => 'required|min:4'
      ]);

    $email = $request['email'];
    $name = $request['name'];
    $mobile_num = $request['mobile_num'];
    $address = $request['address'];
    $city = $request['city'];
    $district = $request['district'];
    $state = $request['state'];
    $password = bcrypt($request['password']);

    $user = new User();
    $user->email =$email;
    $user->name = $name;
    $user->mobile_num = $mobile_num;
    $user->address = $address;
    $user->city = $city;
    $user->district = $district;
    $user->state = $state;
    $user->password = $password;

    $user->save();

    return redirect()->route('dashboard');

    Auth::login($user);
 }

 public function postSignIn(Request $request)
 { 
    $this -> validate($request,[
        'mobile_num' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
        ]);

   if(Auth::attempt(['mobile_num' => $request['mobile_num'], 'password' =>  $request['password']]))  {

        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }

        return redirect()->back();          
  }

  public function getDashboard()
   {  

         return view('pages.dashboard');
   }


  }
```

routes/web.php :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('home');

Route::post('/signup',[
    'uses' => 'RegisterController@postSignUp',
    'as'   => 'signup'
    ]);

Route::post('/signin',[
    'uses' => 'RegisterController@postSignIn',
    'as'   => 'signin'
    ]);

Route::get('/dashboard',[
     'uses' => 'RegisterController@getDashboard',
     'as'   => 'dashboard',
     'middleware' => 'auth'
    ]);
Route::get('/register',[
     'uses' => 'RegisterController@getRegistrationPage',
     'as'   => 'register',
     'middleware' => 'auth'
    ]);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return `user_register` view which should [extend layout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#extending-a-layout) (in this case it called `welcome`):

```
@extends('welcome')
```

Or you can call `welcome` and [include](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#including-sub-views) `user_register` view:

```
@include('user_auth.user_register')
```

It depends on what you want to achieve, but renaming `welcome` to `layout` and extending it looks like right solution here.

Also rename files to `.blade.php`, because now names are like `welcome.blade` instead of `welcome.blade.php`.

Comment: Please check the code again, I edited it. I already used "@extends('welcome')", sorry didn't add it here in the first place.

Comment: Do you get any error? Please show controller method which returns the view.

Comment: NO, not a single error. Just the form area is missing. And yes I added the controller code also, please have a look.

Comment: Just added again, sorry my net is not working properly.

Comment: I don't see code which is supposed to load the view. You should do this in the appropriate method `return view('user_auth.user_register');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132670/discussion-between-rock-and-alexey-mezenin).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but Please check your route file Have you called user_register route? 
You have set a welcome page as a layout file so When you will call welcome page it displays only header & footer file which you have included.

Comment: Yes, I have checked the routes file again, added it too, you can have a look.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14825794)

Comment: I asked him to check the route file because when I checked I didn't find anything wrong. Sorry, if that wasn't a correct response. @DovydasSopa